# Using existing C# model classes to build an entity diagram (.EDMX)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, edmx

I am porting an application's persistent storage mechanics from SQL Compact to Oracle.

*Current Implementation*

The application implements Entity Framework 5 (EF), but it is pretty tightly coupled: **(a)** there is no *service layer* between EF and the Controllers, and **(b)** there is no `IRepository`-style abstraction between EF and SQL Compact.

The C# models are simple POCOs but are rich with data annotations, and is used "code-first" style to generate DB schema.

*Problem (Oracle)*

I must use Oracle's standard ODP.Net provider. The provider supports EF, but does not support "code-first" methodology, only "model first".

*Intended Solution*

I am trying to find a way to preserve the EF implementation tightly coupled to the controllers, and the richness of the model class annotations, while using them to build the "model-first" style EDMX file that Oracle can swallow. Essentially, I am looking for a way to mimic "code-first".

I was hoping it would be as simple as dragging my C# objects onto the EDMX file but it seems like there's much more going on.

### Question

How can I build an .EDMX file using C# models that already exist? If it is not possible, what is the next best solution for accomplishing this goal?

#### Note: Please do not recommend paid-for third party products. The solution must be doable with Visual Studio, `C#`, an open source library, or some combination.

Comment: See note above - 3rd party paid for products cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have DbContext you can use 'EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx()' to write your model as the edmx file that you should be able to open with the designer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. There are hiccups with things like mapping `bool` to `NUMBER(1,0)` that fail, or how the EDMX writer does not acknowledge annotations or restrictions in the fluent API (ex. `.HasMaxLength(50)`) and thus strings become an `NCLOB` rather than `NVARCHAR2(50)`... but all in all it helps me save a ton of time even if it is only used to build the initial DB schema. If you would, elaborate a little more and I'll mark yours the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: This is because Oracle not only has different types than Sql Server but also it does not have some types that EF uses (like bool). I think you will need to re-do S-Side (most of this should be just easy with replace in the text editor/VS). EdmxWriter should reflect annotations and fluent configuration - otherwise different types of hierarchies could not be modeled with CodeFirst. EdmxWriter is used internally to build csdl/ssdl/msl artifacts that are passed to the underlying ObjectContext. As a result what's not passed in these artifact is not reflected as ObjectContext works on these.

Comment: You're right about the annotations; I spoke too soon. It looks like the mapping of bool to number is a documented issue and one that the model first representation handles i guess. but fluid mapping (much like code first) still chokes on. I'm gonna read about that one; otherwise yeah, I'll have to use bool on a ViewModel and keep the Model with something else, even a T/F char or 1/0 number. :( again, you're the man.

Comment: Know anything about mapping `bool` to `NUMBER(1,0)`? I spoke with Alex Keh and read the documentation about using a config section to note `<add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />` but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Alex is one of the guys behind ODP.NET - I think you need to ask him or bing/google for more details. I am not very familiar with Oracle, sorry.

Comment: Yes, he has been awesome help. The mapping is working partially now, but still a `MetadataException` reading `error 0040: The Type number(1,0) is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.` More homework yet. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It just means that the type is not recognized. Have you changed the providerManifestToken (on the Schema element) or it still uses SqlClient (which is SqlServer) as written by EdmxWriter...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The place that article was posted reorganized their URLs.  Fixed the reference.  Sorry for the broken link.

[Here](http://www.oakwoodsys.com/adding-annotations-data-model-first-entities/) is a blog post that I wrote that explains how to use the MetaDataTypeAttribute to allow you the benefit of all the code-first annotation work when utilizing a newly-generated database-first/model-first edmx.

While it won't let you build the .edmx from the models, you can at least generate from database and then use the current code-first classes as metadata.

Comment: There is no database; thus "model first". I need to build an .EDMX file that Oracle can use to build the schema. I am looking for a way to engineer this file from the existing annotated C# classes.

Comment: Fair enough.  In most cases, I prefer to use the db tools to design the database and then generate the model from that.  But I am not familiar with the Oracle tools at all.  If you're intending to build the model first and have the database generated from that, then my process could still help after everything is built, but I apologize for missing the main point.  I don't know of a way to generate the model from the POCO code-first classes.

Comment: Yep, using the EDMX to build the Oracle schema is easy (built-in). What I'm trying to do is avoid having to use the designer to build C# classes I've already built. You'd think the EDMX designer would be smart enough to allow you to drop C# classes on its surface and build the underlying EDMX data. Oh well.. thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

**@Pawel** provided the the underlying answer, `EdmxWriter`. His answer is marked and thanks go to him. My answer is just to provide more detail, a reference to Oracle documentation, and a simple code example:

---

#### C# to EDMX

The `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure` namespace provides a static `EdmxWriter` for this purpose:

```
// 1. Instantiate your DbContext derived type
var db = new AppContext();

// 2. Instantiate an XmlWriter
var xw = XmlWriter.Create("models.edmx");

// 3. Write to file.
EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(db, xw);
```

The resulting EDMX file can be added to the project/solution and opened with the designer.

#### EDMX to Oracle Schema

With a few changes to the EDMX file properties (see ["Model First" Step 2](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm)), you can then `Generate Database from Model` to the Oracle-syntax SQL scripts used to build the db schema.

***Note:** As Pawel noted in comment, the EDMX writer will acknowledge and respect both data annotation attributes (ex. `[MaxLength]`) and fluent api configs `.HasMaxLength(50)`, but it does not handle certain data type mapping issues between C#/EntityFramework and Oracle's db types.*